# Javascript form validation does not appear to be working at all on MVC file upload application

Tags: javascript, validation, model-view-controller

None of my form validation appears to be working for my MVC application.  I am building an MVC application that has a form that uploads a file (supposed to be jpg only) to a folder and writes the location and details about the file to the database.  My upload works and I everything writes to the database but my form validation does not even appear to be working.  I am able to upload any file type I want and it does not seem to be enforcing mandatory fields.

I am not sure where I am going wrong as this is my first MVC application that I have built.

```
@model GarbHelper.Models.Sources

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
    <html>
        <head>

            <script src="@Url.Content(" ~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js ")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Add").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#Image").change(function () {

            // Get uploaded file extension
            var extension = $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            // Create array with the files extensions that we wish to upload
            var validFileExtensions = ['jpg'];
            //Check file extension in the array.if -1 that means the file extension is not in the list.
            if ($.inArray(extension, validFileExtensions) == -1) {
                alert("Sorry!! Upload only 'jpg' file")
                // Clear fileuload control selected file
                $(this).replaceWith($(this).val('').clone(true));
                //Disable Submit Button
                $('#Add').prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                // Check and restrict the file size to 128 KB.
                if ($(this).get(0).files[0].size > (262144)) {
                    alert("Sorry!! Max allowed file size is 256 kb");
                    // Clear fileuload control selected file
                    $(this).replaceWith($(this).val('').clone(true));
                    //Disable Submit Button
                    $('#Add').prop('disabled', true);
                }
                else {
                    //Enable Submit Button
                    $('#Add').prop('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        });
            $("#Add").click(function() {
                if ($("#Wiki_Commons_Image_Link").val() = null || $("#Artist_Author").val() || $("#Title").val() || $("#Date_Of_Item").val() || $("#Medium").val() || $("#Location").val() | $("#Accession_Number").val() | $("#Source_URL").val() | $("#Description").val()) {
                    alert("Please fill out required fields(*)");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        });
</script>
<style>

    <style >
    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    thead {
        background-color: skyblue;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {<br />
            <table cellpadding="5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">Add a Source</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"> Please fill <span style="color:red">(*)</span> out below fields and click Submit to add a Source </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Image)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Image, new { type = "file" }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Wiki_Commons_Image_Link)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Wiki_Commons_Image_Link, new { @type = "url" }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Artist_Author)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Artist_Author, new { maxlength = 256 }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { maxlength = 256 }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Date_Of_Item)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date_Of_Item, new { maxlength = 256 }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Medium)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Medium, new { maxlength = 256 }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Location)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Location, new { maxlength = 256 }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Accession_Number)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Accession_Number, new { maxlength = 256 }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Source_URL)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Source_URL, new { @type = "url" }) </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)<b style="color:red"> *</b> </td>
                    <td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description, new { maxlength = 15000 }) </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:right"> <input type="submit" id="Add" value="Add" /> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `html`, `head`, `body` tags from this View. Your `Shared/_Layout.cshtlml` will have those, and this view will render inside `@RenderBody()`. BTW, your validation code works

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can add event handler directly to the element as shown below.

`<input type="submit" id="Add" value="Add" onSubmit="Validate()" />`

or like this `<input type="submit" id="Add" value="Add" onSubmit="return Validate()" />`

and `Validate()` function return true/false depending on some condition. The difference is, in the first one return value is ignored but not in second case.

Or you can use `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not a Javascript issue but a MVC issue of how views are rendered in Layout page, as I can see you have tags in individual view page rather than a layout page.

By default `/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` will have `html`,`head`, `body` tags. There is also a HelperResult `@RenderBody()` method where all the views that use's this layout will be rendered.

So you are erroneously duplicating `html`,`head`, `body` tags inside your view.
If you did view page source on your rendered page, you should see the problem.

Also, place your script inside

```
@section scripts{
  <script> 
       // Your script 
  </script>
}
```

Your Layout should have `@RenderScript("scripts", required:false)` near the end of the body tag, where your `@section scripts` will be rendered.

Comment: When I try to add the RenderScript section to my _Layout.cshtml I get a compilation error.  I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Did you try `@RenderScript()` ? This method is inside System.Web.WebPages namespace